# Trying to read emails with specific subject from Gmail

Tags: python, gmail-imap, imaplib

I am trying to read an email in Gmail that has a specific subject and get the OTP value within the email. I am using imaplib

```
  import imaplib  
  def get_CreateAccount_OTP(self, email_type):
        gmail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
        gmail.login(self.gmail_username, self.gmail_password)
        gmail.select('Inbox', readonly=True)

     type, data = gmail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "Here\'s your Texas by Texas email verification.")')
```

I got the type returned as Ok, but the data as below

```
 data = {list: 1} [b'']
 0 = {bytes: 0} b''
  __len__ = {int} 1
```

After that line, it's not going into the below "for loop"

```
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, data = gmail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = str(email.message_from_string(raw_email_string))
    email_message_list = email_message.split('\n')
    RE_TIME_STAMP_PATTERN = re.compile((r'\d{6}'))
    for line in email_message_list:
        print(line)
        if 'Your sign-in verification code is ' in line:
            self.OTP = re.findall(RE_TIME_STAMP_PATTERN, line)[0]
            break
    self.log.info("OTP:",self.OTP)
    return self.OTP
```

Note: I am new to Python and learning it slowly. Please bare with my silly questions
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi ! Are you using [Gmail IMAP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap) in your code? Also, what is your actual intention with this piece of code and what is the main issue you are encountering, that the data is not getting into the for loop? Could you log ```data[0]``` before it enters the for loop to make sure the issue is not there? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, I am using iMaplib.py. I want to read all the emails with the specified subject. But the Data is returning empty. I replaced the Subject with Body and now the script is working. Not sure if the subject method is wrong. There is no error displayed

Comment: Glad you managed to solve your problem. Could you please formalise your comment into an answer so that other users with similar issues can easily find the answer? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Its same script I used, The issue is with the special char in the string. "Here's" once I remove that text it worked fine. Now I want to try with special chars as I will be using Spanish language with Unicode ex. "Favor de verificar su correo electrónico". "ó" is the unicode and the search method is not returning any email messages. Not sure how to treat the special chars. Also when the string has " ' " char no emails are returned. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue that the string has special char and the implib is not converting the char to Unicode. So I have to remove the word that has the special char in my string.

```
 import imaplib  
  def get_CreateAccount_OTP(self, email_type):
        subject="your Texas by Texas email verification."
        gmail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
        gmail.login(self.gmail_username, self.gmail_password)
        gmail.select('Inbox', readonly=True)

     type, data = gmail.search(None, '(UNSEEN SUBJECT "%s")' % subject)
  
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, data = gmail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = str(email.message_from_string(raw_email_string))
    email_message_list = email_message.split('\n')
    RE_TIME_STAMP_PATTERN = re.compile((r'\d{6}'))
    for line in email_message_list:
        print(line)
        if 'Your sign-in verification code is ' in line:
            self.OTP = re.findall(RE_TIME_STAMP_PATTERN, line)[0]
            break
    self.log.info("OTP:",self.OTP)
    return self.OTP
```